# ggsurvplot (Survminer) draw rectangle on plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm using ggsurvplot to draw survival curve comparisons.
I'd like to customise my plot by drawing a shaded rectangle on a certain interval between two values of the x-axis.
How can I do this?

Assume I am running the following code:

```
require("survival")
fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

# Basic survival curves
ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung)
```

Let's say I want to add a shaded rectangle between Time 0 and Time 250.

Thanks a lot in advance

Luca

Answer (score 2):

A `ggsurvplot` object is basically a list which contains a ggplot object as an element `plot`. Hence, you could always manipulate this `plot` element using default methods, e.g. you could use `annotate` to add e rectangle. However, the tricky part with adding a new layer is that it will be plotted on top of the existing layers. Hence one has to take account of that and add it at the right position in the list of `layers`. In the code below I simply added the rectangle as the first element of the list of `layers`:

```r
library(survival)
library(survminer)

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
p <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung)

p$plot$layers <- c(annotate(geom = "rect", xmin = 0, xmax = 250, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "purple"), p$plot$layers)

p
```

[image]